# Understanding Domain Events

Tags: c#

I am trying to understand the domain events. Let's say I have a customer object and it raises the OnCustomerInserted event. I want my email service class to subscribe to that event so that whenever the event is raised an email is sent.

```
public class Customer
    {
        public delegate void CustomerInsertedHandler();

        public event CustomerInsertedHandler CustomerInserted; 

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public void OnCustomerInserted()
        {
            if(CustomerInserted != null)
            {
                CustomerInserted(); 
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is the CustomerRepository:

```
public class CustomerRepository
    {
        public void Add(Customer customer)
        {
            // add the customer 

            customer.Id = 2;

            if(customer.Id > 0)
            {
                // raise the event! 
            }
        }
    }
```

Finally, here is the simple EmailService class:

```
 public class EmailService
    {
        public EmailService()
        {

        }

        public void Send()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Email has been sent!");
        }
    }
```

UPDATE:

Still the code below is bit ugly!

```
public class CustomerRepository
    {
        public delegate void CustomerInsertedHandler(Customer newCustomer);
        public event CustomerInsertedHandler CustomerInserted; 

        public void OnCustomerInserted(Customer newCustomer)
        {
            if (CustomerInserted != null)
                CustomerInserted(newCustomer); 
        }

        public void Add(Customer customer)
        {
            // add the customer 

            customer.Id = 2;


            if(customer.Id > 0)
            {
                var emailService = new EmailService();
                CustomerInserted += emailService.Send; 

                // raise the event!
                OnCustomerInserted(customer);
            }
        }


}
```

I updated my repository and is using StructorMap to create instance of the Repository

```
public class CustomerRepository : ICustomerRepository
    {
        public delegate void CustomerInsertedHandler(Customer newCustomer);
        public event CustomerInsertedHandler CustomerInserted;
        private IEmailService _emailService; 

        public CustomerRepository(IEmailService emailService)
        {
            _emailService = emailService;
            CustomerInserted += _emailService.Send; 
        }
```

The code is still not good since now the CustomerRepository constructor is getting crowded. The EmailService is clean as follows:

```
 public class EmailService : IEmailService
    {
        public EmailService()
        {

        }

        public void Send(Customer customer)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Email Sent!"); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Move subscription code _out of_ `CustomerRepository` and move it to `EmailService` constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `CustomerInserted` from `Customer` to `CustomerRepository` and you'll be just fine. And tweak `CustomerInsertedHandler` so that it will contain a reference to the inserted `Customer`  object:

```
public delegate void CustomerInsertedHandler(Customer insertedCustomer);
```

Or do it more in line with the rest of .NET:

```
public delegate void CustomerInsertedHandler(object sender, CustomerInsertedEventArgs e);
```

So the overall structure will be as follows:

```
public delegate void CustomerInsertedHandler(Customer newCustomer);

public class CustomerRepository
{
    public event CustomerInsertedHandler CustomerInserted; 

    private void RaiseCustomerInserted(Customer newCustomer)
    {
        if(CustomerInserted != null)
            CustomerInserted(newCustomer); 
    }

    public void Add(Customer customer)
    {
        // add the customer 

        customer.Id = 2;

        if(customer.Id > 0)
            RaiseCustomerInserted(customer);
    }
}

public class EmailService
{
    // Using autoproperty syntax from C# 3.0
    public CustomerRepository { get; set; }

    public EmailService()
    {

    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        //
        // You need to get hold of a reference to CustomerRepository somehow.
        // Google for either "Dependency Injection" or "Service Locator".
        CustomerRepository.CustomerInserted += delegate(Customer c)
            { Send(c); };

    }

    public void Send(Customer customer)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Email has been sent to " + customer.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: but how do I subscribe to event to the email service. I have moved the event to the repository!

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will check out DI and Service Locator.

Comment: Thanks! I updated the above post to include the CustomerRepository in the StructureMap and it creates an object of IEmailService.

Answer (score 1):

Udi Dahan has a good example on his blog: http://www.udidahan.com/2008/08/25/domain-events-take-2/.

The basic idea is to create an Event as a first class object in your domain model. Then whoever needs to can subscribe to the event, and also publish it.

Comment: Please check out my implementation above!